# Windows 7 source-specific multicast (SSM)

Tags: windows-7, multicast, video-streaming, igmp

We are planning to stream video feeds over multicast to managed Windows 7 devices.

Does Windows 7 support source-specific multicast at the OS layer (as the receiver)? It appears that Windows XP and Windows Vista both support it, but I can't find any specific information that confirms the support of doing this on a standard Windows 7 device.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a quick test on my Windows 7 box and found that it supports receiving SSM.

Comment: While this may answer the question it would be preferable for you to post evidence or other results.